# How to find typeof card after entering 5-6 digit input and change card image in angular

Tags: angular

I'm working on angular.
without using any 3rd party package is it possible to detect the card type on keypress??

Here are some of the work I did but getting log as null.
Help me with this .

```
 checklength(number) {
AmexCardnumber(inputtxt) {
  var cardno = /^(?:3[47][0-9]{13})$/;
  return cardno.test(inputtxt);
}
VisaCardnumber(inputtxt) {
  var cardno = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/;
  return cardno.test(inputtxt);
}
MasterCardnumber(inputtxt) {
  var cardno = /^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{14})$/;
  return cardno.test(inputtxt);
}
DiscoverCardnumber(inputtxt) {
  var cardno = /^(?:6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12})$/;
  return cardno.test(inputtxt);
}
DinerClubCardnumber(inputtxt) {
  var cardno = /^(?:3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11})$/;
  return cardno.test(inputtxt);
}
JCBCardnumber(inputtxt) {
  var cardno = /^(?:(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$/;
  return cardno.test(inputtxt);
}
IsValidCreditCardNumber(cardNumber) {
  var cardType = null;
  if (this.VisaCardnumber(cardNumber)) {
    cardType = "visa";
  } else if (this.MasterCardnumber(cardNumber)) {
    cardType = "mastercard";
  } else if (this.AmexCardnumber(cardNumber)) {
    cardType = "americanexpress";
  } else if (this.DiscoverCardnumber(cardNumber)) {
    cardType = "discover";
  } else if (this.DinerClubCardnumber(cardNumber)) {
    cardType = "dinerclub";
  } else if (this.JCBCardnumber(cardNumber)) {
    cardType = "jcb";
  }
  return cardType;
}
```

Comment: are all these functions inside `checklength`?

Comment: Can you share whole ts file to see the logic that you are using?